# Where do I put jquery Animation code in my Wordpress theme? Does everything go into a page template PHP file?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, file, templates, animation

I'm working on sprucing up a few sites and have been working on animated sections using jQuery scripts. I'm a graphic designer so code is not my thing, but I'm learning a lot to be able to do my sites without looking to static and complement my designs.

I believe I need to put he code in a PHP file, but how do I reference the jQuery base files and say I'm using an animated logo section on my main page?

I don't want to mess up that page template by adding the code there, can I add a separate PHP file like `logoani.php` to my WP files and somehow call that out for where I need it?

Okay, I have loaded the proper scripts into the WP folder on my server, then added the code suggested below to the `.php` with my functions. So now I'm looking at adding the rest of the code into my template.

Will the code suggested below insert the extra HTML needed for that script, and if so, how do I make sure it's placed in the correct module on my WP page?

I know this is a lame question, but I'm really trying to learn this stuff, and oddly haven't found a good tutorial on what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add JS-Files to your wordpress-theme, add this code  to the functions.php-file in your wordpress-theme-folder:

```
function my_extrajs() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/yourCode.js"></script>
<?php }

add_action('wp_head', 'my_extrajs');
```

wp_head and so on, are  called action hooks.
For more info: http://www.nathanrice.net/blog/an-introduction-to-wordpress-action-hooks/

Comment: Ok, so that tells it to look for the files at those paths indicated, then I add the HTML part into the main Page PHP I believe.

Comment: It will work without changing the main Page PHP-File. The functions.php-File is in /wp-includes/functions.php. The HTML-code in my answer will be written into every page automatically.

Comment: Thanks man, very helpful answer. Finally logged on here after just reading posts for help, and it's a great site that I will be making a daily stop on.

Comment: Your welcome :)
The File you need should be there too: /wp-content/themes/YourThemeName/functions.php

Comment: Yep, looking at it now. I have a pretty good idea of file structure for the wp sites on my server, I constantly study them for future use. I figure if I'm learning code, I need to try and familiarize myself.

Comment: What do you mean with _correct module_? Do you want to include the code just in a specific page? If so, you can use conditional tags, for example: `if(is_page(42)) { add_action('wp_head', 'my_extrajs'); }` [more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)

Comment: I am actually using Ithemes Builder as a base, which sets the pages up in modules, which I'm seeing isn't a standard thing in some of the other themes I have downloaded. I'm looking through my builder. Hold theme and another theme to see how these things are inserted into each one, hopefully that will lead me to where to insert the code.

Comment: **Dont print direct js calls in WordPress Head** There is a function for that, wp_enqueue_script.

Comment: @dop-trois thank you for this answer, came right up in google, hated word press, but now I can finally make it do what I want!

Answer (score 1):

#### You don't ever want to print direct calls to scripts in your header.

WordPress provides a function, [***`wp_enqueue_script`***](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script.) Plugins rely on this function for compatibility.

If your script relies on jQuery then add 'jquery' to the dependencies array.  If it's a build in script you don't need to enqueue it if you have it listed.

```
function get_my_js() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'handle', 'src', array( 'dependency', 'another-dependency', true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'get_my_js' );
```

#### See [Where is the right place to register and enqueue javascript and css files](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/21579/251) for more information.

Comment: Here is a very good answer on [why you should use wp_enqueue_script](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/21579/251).

Answer (score -1):

you can do this in the same way doing it in a simple html page. put your script inside the template folder then include the script with < script > tag in whichever page you want .Dont forget to give the link as .

> src='echo bloginfo(template_url); ?>/relativePathFromTemplateFolder.js'